# Changing elements in an Array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
def q(s):
    n = len(s)
    v = numpy.zeros(n, dtype=float)
```

`s` is a vector containing however many elements I wish (`[s0,s1,s2,....,sn-2,sn-1]`) , and I intend to then create an array (initial full of zeros) that is of the same size as `s`.

My aim is to then to change the zero elements in this array to `[s1/s0 , s2/s1 , s3/s2..., sn-1/sn-2]`.

I understand that a for loop is required, but I am finding it difficult to program this. Could anybody offer a hand?  Thank you.

Comment: Please try something first, then if you're stuck tell us what you tried and where you got stuck and the Python community here at [so] would love to help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an array of zeros first.

```
[b / a for a, b in zip(s, s[1:])]
```

---

**Explanation**

`s` your list, `s[1:]` is you list except for the first element.

`zip` puts them together in pairs, like `[[s0, s1], [s1, s2],... [sn-2, sn-1]]`.

Then you just divide the second element of each sublist by the first.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, you are correct. I changed the order of division instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help and I can see that this would work. But for this function in particular, I want to create an array of zeros initially; and then change the zeros. (Even though I know its long winded and unnecessary!)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit loop if you're using a NumPy array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], dtype=float)
>>> a[1:]/a[:-1]
array([ 2.        ,  1.5       ,  1.33333333,  1.25      ])
```